# Metal Gear Solid V Sound Bug

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I have a problem with voices in Metal Gear Solid V.
In mission briefings or cutscenes the voices are missing.

I Played until i got DD and the voice goes missing at the moment Snake should talk. After that every voice which is not "noise" (NPC's voices when run into them etc.) is missing.

I recorded gameplay to show the bug, but in the recorded video I have all voices.

All other sounds exist, and they disappear just at the moment Snake should talk.

Does somebody know how this could be fixed or where I could search for the problem?

Hardware: PC

Grapicscard: GTX970

Sound: Logitech G633

Platform: Steam

Already searched the Steam forum and this issue never showed up there

Settings: Resolution: 3840x2160 Borderless Window and Fullscreen

Comment: Please indicate what platform you're experiencing this issue, and if on PC, indicate point of sale (i.e. Steam). Per where you could search for the problem, you could start at the point of sale (i.e., Steam has a list of similar issues with this title in their community forums you can check out).

Comment: A Lisst with similar issues? i only found pinned the Template how to report but no real list with issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I Found the Answer to that Problem:
Logitech Gaming Software.

Due some kind of weird is the Surround-Feature broken. A Update of the Logitech Gaming Software helped that i got sound.

It was not Possible to change the Logitech G633 to a other System than 7.1. In Windows AND Logitech exist only the Option for 7.1 and not stereo or other x.1 Systems.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Steam Community discussion [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/287700/discussions/0/527273983048774247/):

The fix to the same issue was:

- Redownload files

User TopKak writes:

> To do that go to your library>right click MGSV>properties>local files and select to verify.

- Switch audit to stereo
- Uninstall / Reinstall game.

It may be a good opportunity to check and ensure you have updated both video and audio drivers.

Nividia is almost annoying in how often they update drivers, but they're good about keeping things updated. From past experience, sometimes the video and audio drivers can cause a conflict, but it's rare.

Comment: Drivers up to date, Revalidated the Files twice, even downloaded the Beta (but this is not compatible with my savefile). The Point i see wich can it be will be the Stereo sound...

Comment: What about converting to stereo output?

Comment: Also check the center speaker volume